# SQL Script Issue

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the error I receive when running this script on oracle iacademy 
ORA-00905: missing keyword
I can't figure out what is the missing keyword from the script. The problem is mainly pointed towards the SELECT instruction.

```
DROP TABLE c_furnizori;
DROP TABLE c_adrese;

CREATE TABLE C_ADRESE
    (ida NUMBER(4,0),
     localitate VARCHAR(30),
     strada VARCHAR(30),
     numar NUMBER(3,0)    
    );

CREATE TABLE C_FURNIZORI
    (idf NUMBER(4,0),
     numef VARCHAR(20),
     ida NUMBER(4,0)
    );

ALTER TABLE C_ADRESE ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ADRESE PRIMARY KEY (ida);
ALTER TABLE C_FURNIZORI ADD CONSTRAINT PK_FURNIZORI PRIMARY KEY (idf);

ALTER TABLE C_FURNIZORI ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FURNIZORI_ADRESAFURNIZORI FOREIGN KEY (ida) REFERENCES C_ADRESE(ida);

INSERT INTO C_ADRESE (ida,localitate,strada,numar) VALUES ('1','Sighisoara','Aurel Vlaicu','33');
INSERT INTO C_ADRESE (ida,localitate,strada,numar) VALUES ('2','Cluj Napoca','Mihail Kogalniceanu','2');
INSERT INTO C_ADRESE (ida,localitate,strada,numar) VALUES ('3','Bucuresti','Mihai Eminescu','1');
INSERT INTO C_ADRESE (ida,localitate,strada,numar) VALUES ('4','Brasov','Suisul Castelului','4');
INSERT INTO C_ADRESE (ida,localitate,strada,numar) VALUES ('5','Tg. Mures','Clinicii','124');

INSERT INTO C_FURNIZORI (idf,numef,ida) VALUES ('1','Super Truck','3');
INSERT INTO C_FURNIZORI (idf,numef,ida) VALUES ('2','Autoeco','1');
INSERT INTO C_FURNIZORI (idf,numef,ida) VALUES ('3','GalaxyAuto','5');
INSERT INTO C_FURNIZORI (idf,numef,ida) VALUES ('4','Epiesa','2');
INSERT INTO C_FURNIZORI (idf,numef,ida) VALUES ('5','Eurocar Auto','4');

SELECT C_FURNIZORI.numef AS "Nume furnizor", C_ADRESE.localitate AS "Localitate", C_ADRESE.strada AS "Strada", C_ADRESE.numar AS "Numar" 
FROM C_FURNIZORI JOIN C_ADRESE
ON C_FURNIZORI.ida = C_ADRESE.ida;
```

Comment: Oracle version? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f76d5/1 your code works fine

Comment: I agree with @realnumber3012 that the code looks fine.  Perhaps you have some unintended character in the data that is invisible, but not a space.

Comment: 11g I think. The error might be related to the fact that I'm trying to run the table creation script alongside the query?

Comment: what exactly is "oracle iacademy" ?. Apex?

Comment: It's possible... not sure what iAcademy is. In any case, on an actual Oracle database, I was able to run your `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements and the `SELECT` query and everything worked perfectly fine. Now I have the address of **Autoeco** on my screen! Do you have an Oracle installation? If not, did you know that you can install Oracle for free - even the most recent, full featured version, as long as it is for learning and evaluation, not for commercial use? No point in "playing" on web sites when you can learn a lot more by working on an actual Oracle DB.

Comment: No, it's like a platform for students made purely for teaching data bases. Indeed, it was the fact that I can't run a query alongside creation of the tables.

Comment: delete bottom half and try again. if error is still there repeat. if error is gone add half of the bottom part and repeat.